# Derived class: use stream operator overloaded in templated base class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

The following code produces an "Undefined symbols" error. How can it be modified to work properly?

I'm trying to make an interface which allows printing data regardless of its type. The derived classes determine the type of data to be printed.

```
template<typename T>
class Base {

    T data_;

public:
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const Base<T> &);

};

template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Base<T> &) {
    // ...
    return os;
}


class Derived : public Base<int> {

};

Derived d;


std::cout << d << '\n';
```

Comment: To begin with, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Are all of the code in the same source file? Do you implement the `operator<<` function in a separate source file?

Comment: You need a separate `template<class U>` appearing before the `friend` function declaration.

Comment: This cppcon 2018 talk answers your question [CppCon 2018: Dan Saks “Making New Friends”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POa_V15je8Y)

Comment: The solution is to inline in the class the operator definition.